# how to add an overlaying color over an image with css

Tags: css

if I have an image like so:

```
<img src="inshot1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">​​​​​​​
```

and on hover I want that block to be covered in a color. So for example when you hover over it you get a block of red color with the same height and width. So an overlay basically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done multiple ways but you can just wrap it in a `<div>` with a `background-color` and set `visibility: hidden` on the image on `:hover`

```css
div { 
  background: red; 
  display: inline-block; 
}

img { 
  display: block; 
}

div:hover img { 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Here are two ways you can do this - both involve wrapping the image in a containing element.

**Use the Container's Background**

You can set the background of the containing element to red and then decrease the images opacity on hover:

The HTML looks like this:

```
<!-- Uses background color to fade color from behind. -->
<div id="background">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food" height="100" width="100" />
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
div { position: relative; float: left; }
img { display: block; }

#background { background: red; }
#background:hover img { opacity: 0.5; }
```

**Use a Sibling Element**

You can nest an empty span and use it as an absolutely positioned sibling which can serve as the overlay. Check this out - here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Uses empty span to overlay color. -->
<div id="overlay">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food" height="100" width="100" />
    <span></span>
<div>​
```

And the CSS would look like this:

```
div { position: relative; float: left; }
img { display: block; }

#overlay span {
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#overlay:hover span { opacity: 0.5; }
```

You can try out a demo of each solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jimjeffers/mG78d/1/

**Possible Gotcha**

It's important to note that in order for the containing element to match the size of your image you need to do one of four things:

1. Float the containing element.
2. Absolutely position the containing element.
3. Set the containing element to display: inline-block.
4. Explicitly set the height and width of the containing element to match the image's dimensions.

In my jsfiddle example I set the divs to float: left;.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using pseudo-elements. Note that not all [browsers support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Aafter) pseudo-elements.

```css
.container {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.container::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1641499303764-a9e3a93a72e1?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTY0MjQxODc3MA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" />
</div>
```